# How to add conditional join in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe join condition like

> df1.as("main_data")
>           .join(df2.as("mcp"),df1.col("id").equalTo(df2.col("id")) and df1.col("name").equalTo(df2.col("name"))

In this join the second check is conditional

> ie df1.col("name").equalTo(df2.col("name")) should be performed only
>   if includeNameFlag is false

How can I add this to my dataframe join

Tried to include the condition as a string and appended along with join

```
var joinVar = ""

if(includeNameFlag == false){

    joinVar = """and df1.col("name").equalTo(df2.col("name"))"""

}else{
    joinVar = ""
}

df1.as("main_data")

.join(df2.as("mcp"),df1.col("id").equalTo(df2.col("id"))+ joinVar)
```

But that didnt helped.It ran into error like cannot resolve id= id + name =name

Tried to use when and where conditions but both requres column type

Any other solution to use this condition in dataframe join ?

: [solution](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2018/03/conditional-join-in-spark-using.html?m=1)

Comment: Is there any exception or another output?

Comment: If I understand right, you experience a syntax issue ("both requires column type"). It is unclear from the question what exactly doesn't work. However, it seems to me you have two issues:
1. you're trying to concat a Column type with a string. 
2. The and operator is not used properly. refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#and-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-

you can either use "condition1.and(condition2)" or "condition1 && condition2". "condition1 and condition2" is not valid.

Comment: Use `spark.sql` and formulate the query based on your `if - else`

Comment: Any other ways in dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily done with the `DataFrame` API. Here is a quick example :

```
val df1 = Seq((1, "foo"), (2, "bar")).toDF("id", "name")
val df2 = Seq((1, "bar"), (2, "bar")).toDF("id", "name")
```

I'm using equi-joins which is similar to `equalTo`.

On one hand, according to your description :

```
val includeNameFlag: Boolean = false
val exprs = (if (!includeNameFlag) Seq("id","name") else Seq("id"))

df1.join(df2, exprs).show
// +---+----+
// | id|name|
// +---+----+
// |  2| bar|
// +---+----+
```

On the other hand :

```
val includeNameFlag: Boolean = true
val exprs = (if (!includeNameFlag) Seq("id","name") else Seq("id"))

df1.join(df2, exprs).show
// +---+----+----+
// | id|name|name|
// +---+----+----+
// |  1| foo| bar|
// |  2| bar| bar|
// +---+----+----+
```